# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lretrofit2/GsonConverterFactory;

Tags: android, retrofit, dagger

I have included retrofit in custom library, im getting this error
 at com.mmt.commoncore.rssupport.modules.AppModule.provideRetrofit(AppModule.java:97)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.rssupport.modules.AppModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:27)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.rssupport.modules.AppModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:10)
                                                                            at dagger.internal.ScopedProvider.get(ScopedProvider.java:46)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.rssupport.modules.AppModule_ProvideYipstayApiInterfaceFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideYipstayApiInterfaceFactory.java:23)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.rssupport.modules.AppModule_ProvideYipstayApiInterfaceFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideYipstayApiInterfaceFactory.java:9)
                                                                            at dagger.internal.ScopedProvider.get(ScopedProvider.java:46)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.notificationModule.gcm.GCMRegistrationService_MembersInjector.injectMembers(GCMRegistrationService_MembersInjector.java:27)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.notificationModule.gcm.GCMRegistrationService_MembersInjector.injectMembers(GCMRegistrationService_MembersInjector.java:9)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.rssupport.components.DaggerRsComponent.inject(DaggerRsComponent.java:76)
                                                                            at com.mmt.commoncore.notificationModule.gcm.GCMRegistrationService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationService.java:46)
                                                                            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "retrofit2.GsonConverterFactory" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-uk.co.chrisjenx-calligraphy-2.1.0_3d857cf3e39e24fe75c5e1fc0649101f8c786b4b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.2.0_368c85ce5b387877b354d725ac6f688f6bf6140f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-stetho-okhttp3-1.3.1_587159c92f0ee51be67cd055b89d0c19d9502472-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-stetho-1.3.1_f60927bf861572c3ecd9ae19dfc0eb4820e4ba72-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-sqlite-annotations-1.8.0_1580ce1d1ce5f513f82b3f0fb79c618020d7063b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-sqlite-1.8.0_bbbd74ff221b96cc900c974ea9131a52d563d2f2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-rxjava-1.1.1_ce6be595c06b6845e7802dcf578b87593d3c6f26-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-retrofit-2.0.0_8ef69f394c73c1478d01ea2227c2299c0aa5302f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.mmt.rightstay_host/files/instant-run/dex/slice-replaying-share-1.0.0_89f5b3b13cd7abe58e6a8fa16e2437facb6a6dae-classes.dex", dex file "

Comment: Did you add this dependency in your build.gradle ? `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'`

Comment: @PhilippeA yes is did , 
My problem got solved after I turned of offline sync and given for clean build . Didn't knew what was the reason